# SQL group by multiple columns with where clause returns count of two always

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, count, group-by, where-clause

I am doing a SQL group by multiple columns returns count of two always.

Clearly an examination of the raw data shows that there should be variance in the count.

```
select distinct  col1,col2, col3, COUNT(*) as countDistinct FROM ourTable
  WHERE  ((ourDateEntered >= '20150811') and (col3>0) )
group by col1,col2, col3
order by col1,col2, col3
```

The where clause seems to complicate things, but is needed....

This is SSMS, 2008 R2, though I'm not sure if the exact version matters much here.

The language is T-SQL.

The query runs, but the count is always 2...

An examination of the raw data clearly shows variance in counts, though 2 would be the statistical mode of the data.

Does anyone know how to get an accurate count.

NOTE:  I've tried suggestions from different similar postings and they don't work, including one with the "distinct" keyword, however, I am quite open to any approach with group by or distinct or even another approach.

NOTE 2: Unfortunately, I can't post sample data easily. To be clear I want a count of distinct (x,y,z) triplets where x y z represent col1, 2, and 3

Comment: This is impossible to answer without the data, but I'm 99.9999% certain you misunderstand the grouping operation if you think it should do something else (result in a different values)

Comment: That looks like it would return different values if there were different counts for each grouping. Are you sure it should be returning different values? Sample data would probably help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post sample data easily.  To be clear I want a count of distinct (x,y,z) triplets where x y z represent col1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Can you make up some fake sample data that acts the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the solution is to make a temp table to get rid of the where clause:

```
SELECT * into #TempTable1
FROM
(SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM ourTable
where ((ourDate >= '20150811')) 
group by col1, col2, col3)c
```

Then the query works (no where needed):

```
select distinct  col1,col2, col3, COUNT(*) as countDistinct FROM #TempTable1
group by col1,col2, col3
order by col1,col2, col3
```

Note:  If you are just trying to do a report, and not modifying things, creating a temp table and thereby eliminating some where clauses can greatly simplify the Sql required, in general.